# print dictionary key's minus the list variables

Tags: list, python-2.7, dictionary, key, key-value

So i'm trying to make the game scrabble but i have a little problem and i will try to explain it as good as i can:

I have written a function that generates a dictionary with 7 key's (the key's are the letters you get in your scrabble game and the value of the key means how much times i have that letter in my hand)

```
def deal_hand (7)
```

generates for example the code:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'k': 1, 'o': 1, 'p': 1, 'r': 1}
```

This means we have the following letters: a, b, b, k, o, p, r (we have 2 times a B because the value of that key is 2.

But now i want to create a 2nd function named update_hand, this function should take the word the user made out of the word_list (in this example something like the word 'bob') and should return one of the following 2 dictionaries

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'k': 1, 'o': 0, 'p': 1, 'r': 1}


{'a': 1, 'k': 1, 'p': 1, 'r': 1}
```

My program should return one of these programs because the user used the letters : B, O and B. so there are no B's and O's left.

I have tried a lot to solve this problem now and i came up with the following function:

```
def update_hand(word, hand):
    newd = {}
    for x in word:
        if x in newd:
           newd[x]+=1
    else:
       newd[x] = 1
    hand[x]-=1

    return newd
```

in this code the values of the word and hand in the function are:

```
test_word = raw_input("Enter the word you want to make out of these letters.")

print update_hand(test_word,de_letters)
```

I think im pretty close but i just get the output of the last letter i enter, please help me! :o

Answer (score 0):

```
def update_hand(hand, name):
    delkeys = []
    for n in name:
        if not hand[n]:
            raise ValueError("Cannot remove %s from hand" %n)
        hand[n] -= 1
        if not hand[n]:
            delkeys.append(n)
    for k in delkeys:
        hand.pop(k)
    return hand
```